# Retrieve all the details along with transaction id using PayPal button

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I am very new to Paypal. I want to integrate Paypal with my website. I am trying to use Paypal button. After payment success I was redirect to my page successfully and I was able to retrieve transaction `id` and `amount`. But I need more info regarding transaction.

Could you please help me out to solve this problem?

I've written some code in my success page:

```
<?php
            $item_no            = $_REQUEST['item_number'];
            $item_transaction   = $_REQUEST['tx']; 
            $item_price         = $_REQUEST['amt']; 
            $item_currency      = $_REQUEST['cc'];
          if($item_price=price && item_currency=currency){
                        $content = "<h1>Welcome, Guest</h1>";
            $content .= "<h3>Your payment has been proceeded successfully. Your                
                          transaction id is  $item_transaction</h3>";}
          else{
                   $content="<h3> your payment has been cancelled</h3>";
               }
                        print_r($content);
?>
```

With this code I was able to retrieve transaction `id` but I am unable to retrieve `First name`, `Last name`, `Email` etc..

Can anyone help me out to resolve this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/bizui/IntegrationHub-outside. It will help alot

Comment: i got the solution for this problem. if u want all the details related to the transaction id, with the help of Instant Payment Notification we can achieve this problem.